# Random Multigraph ER-like model?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I was looking into multigraphs recently and I couldn't find a simple *"goto"* model for generating random multigraphs along the lines of the ER model of simple graphs. Specifically, I was hoping to find a model where some type of probabilistic sampling is repeated, generating a binomial degree distribution. I assume one would extend the ER process in some way but I can not seem to find any results around it. To be clear, I am not interested in extending the *configuration model* into a multigraph model, which has been done and is straightforward. Does anyone have any pointers? Thank you